# PDO database insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

hi i have a table in mysql have six fields

```
ID, mobileNumber, firstName, lastName, email, password , rollID
```

ID is autoincrement and i want to insert to it using php

## php code

```
public function run($firstName, $lastName, $mobileNumber, $email, $password, $rePassword) {
        if (!$this->db->isExistedMobile($mobileNumber)) {
            try {
               $query = "INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password, rollID)
                VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :mobileNumber, :email, :password, 'rollID')";
                $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
                $sth->execute(array(
                    ':firstName' => $firstName,
                    ':lastName' => $lastName,
                    ':mobileNumber' => $mobileNumber,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':password' => $password,
                    ':rollID' => "roma"
                ));
                header("location: " . URL . "index");
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            include 'controlers/Error.php';
            $error = new Error();
            $error->index("you enterd a used mobile number");
        }
    }
```

i have this exception

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

the function isExistedMobile always return false so don't worry about it , i don't know where is the wrong , is it in the syntax ? or in the rollID cos i make it static ?
thank you for helping :)

Comment: (I didn't downvote).  Can you explain what is going wrong?  One *presumes* the record is not inserted into the database as expected, but you don't actually say that.  Or perhaps it's the redirect which isn't working as expected?  N.B. It's worth setting `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` during debugging so that any PDO errors are output.

Comment: If you're familiar with try/catch blocks, you could put that whole query in a try{} and catch(PDOException $e). I don't see anything obviously wrong there, so my guess is that one of the variables is undefined or something.

Comment: eqqyal , yes no value inserted and the redirect works good , but no inserted to the db

Comment: scotty yes i am very familiar with try catch i will try it ,

Comment: Also, you should `exit;` or `die()` after using header location, and "controllers" as two Ls in it. :P

Comment: i tried try and catch and no exception found :(, i will update the question to include try and catch

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: You can't catch exceptions unless they're thrown - for that you have to change PDO's error mode as mentioned in my previous comment.  But I'd recommend doing that and then *not* catching the exception so that it is output and you can understand what happened.

Comment: eggyal , this statment $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); shout put in the header of my function ? thank you

Comment: one thing , in my query i didn't put value for ID cos it is autoincrement

Comment: please see rollID , am i wrote it with its value right ?

Comment: i have this exception 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (with [your original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c1faa0ea-f96f-4984-a252-4fe137026c54/view-source)) was that the parameter array had a trailing comma, which created an additional `null` element within it.

I'd recommend reverting to that version (with the literal value for `rollID`) as originally intended, but make sure you remove the trailing comma after `$password`:

```
public function run($firstName, $lastName, $mobileNumber, $email, $password, $rePassword) {
        if (!$this->db->isExistedMobile($mobileNumber)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password, rollID)
                VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :mobileNumber, :email, :password, 'ddd')";
            $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $sth->execute(array(
                ':firstName' => $firstName,
                ':lastName' => $lastName,
                ':mobileNumber' => $mobileNumber,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':password' => $password  // , removed from here
            ));
            header("location: " . URL . "index");
        } else {
            include 'controlers/Error.php';
            $error = new Error();
            $error->index("you enterd a used mobile number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i need the rollID to be static and its value is "roma"

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: You had the right query at the beginning; you just need to remove the superfluous `,`.

Comment: did u mean this ? $query = "INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password, rollID)
                VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :mobileNumber, :email, :password, rollID)";

Comment: Not a good answer imho considering what OP wants, you should instead add a colon to rollID in the query as GolezTrol points out

Comment: @Mahn: Review the OP's modifications to his question to see where he started from - rollID only began moving towards a parameter under his own trial-and-error attempts to resolve the problem I identify in my answer.  As stated in his question, he wants rollID to be "static" (which we can understand to mean "take a constant literal value" from his original post).

Comment: Ah, my mistake then, I didn't look into the modifications. Your answer is indeed correct considering the original question.

Comment: @Mahn: It's a fair point though.  I have updated my answer so that it links to the original version of the question, which hopefully will help others avoid this misunderstanding; perhaps the OP would also consider/permit rolling back his question?